# Javafx Pagination change pageCount issue

Tags: javafx-2

- I create Pagination

  ```
  pagination = PaginationBuilder.create().pageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
      @Override
      public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
          return createChartPage(pageIndex);
      }
  }).build();
  ```
- And i expect that total pages can be changed .
- And when i setPageCount(totalPages). that change pageCountproprety which inform the pageFactory and make callback with index = 0 ;

  ### - My Problem.
- I want the page index not change when i change the PageCount.
- In other word how can i removeChangeListener from pageCountProperty.

Comment: Setting to 0 - is the expected behavior for the case, when count of pages changes, AFAIR. There is no way to remove listener directly.

Comment: But iam zooming over pagination contents and when i zoom in total pages decease and increase when zoom out and i want to in the be on the page which i zoom over it .
**I take care if the current page index more that total i decrease it by 1**

Answer (score 1):

Use this workaround on the factory method until it's fixed in the JDK:

```
 private Parent createPage(Integer pageIndex) {

    // Fix for Pagination.getPageCount resetting the current index to 0
    if (Math.abs(previousPageIndex - pageIndex) > 1) {
        mainPagination.setCurrentPageIndex(previousPageIndex);
        return root.get(previousPageIndex);
    } else {
        // Normal navigation
        previousPageIndex = pageIndex;
        return root.get(pageIndex);
    }

}
```